# function running before useEffect finishes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code:

```
const ChatsPage = () => {
    let username = ""
    let secret = ""
    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .post('http://localhost:3001/authenticate')
            .then((response) => {
                username = response.data.username
                secret = response.data.secret
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }, []);

    let chatProps = useMultiChatLogic('xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx', username, secret);

    return (
        <div style={{ height: '100vh' }}>
            <MultiChatSocket {...chatProps} />
            <MultiChatWindow {...chatProps} style={{ height: '100vh' }} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

The problem with it is that `let chatProps = useMultiChatLogic('xxxx-xx-x-xx-xxx', username, secret);` is running before the `useEffect` is finished. I have tried to move it inside the .then, where it gives a hooks error, and a few other things but nothing has worked.

Comment: That's not a problem, that's exactly what you should expect to happen. That's the whole point of using `useEffect`. You need to move those values to _state_, and handle the fact that they don't initially have a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing a basic understanding of React. Check out a tutorial on state, `useEffect` and control flow in general.

`useEffect` is asynchronous--the callback is executed by React after the first render and whenever the variables captured in the dependency array are set. Your dependency array is empty, so this `useEffect` runs once in the component's lifecycle, after the first render.

I have no idea what the Multi stuff is, but you could try something like this:

```js
const ChatsPageLoader = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [secret, setSecret] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .post('http://localhost:3001/authenticate')
      .then((response) => {
        setUsername(response.data.username);
        setSecret(response.data.secret);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);

  if (!username || !secret) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return <ChatsPage username={username} secret={secret} />;
};

const ChatsPage = ({username, secret}) => {
  const chatProps = useMultiChatLogic('xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx', username, secret);

  return (
    <div style={{ height: '100vh' }}>
      <MultiChatSocket {...chatProps} />
      <MultiChatWindow {...chatProps} style={{ height: '100vh' }} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here, on the first render we know the request hasn't finished because `username` and `secret` are still the default empty strings, so we render a loading message. After that's rendered, the `useEffect` runs and kicks off the request.

After a few moments, the response arrives and we set state for `username` and `secret`, which triggers another render. On this render, the `username` and `secret` values from the response are available (I assume they're guaranteed to be nonempty strings in the response), so the loading message isn't rendered. Instead, we render the `ChatsPage` component, which accepts props with the response's data.

The extra component is necessary because hooks like `useMultiChatLogic` [have to be declared above any conditions](https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning). If this isn't a hook, then the call can happen in the component function body after the `if` and no extra component is needed.

---

The golden rule of React is that state is immutable, so if any data changes from one render to the next, it has to be done through `setState`, not `=`.

Comment: thanks for sharing this detailed answer, really appreciate it. I didn't realize the setting the states part, as well as conditionally rendering the pages. I appreciate it a lot, helping me learn!